# Apple Mach-O linker error using Xcode 6.1 and unity 4.6

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode6.1

Trying to build a unity project in `Xcode`. It gives me this error. Cannot figure it out. I am using `unity 4.6 and Xcode 6.1`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "UnityGetGLViewController()", referenced from:
      +[GameCenterManager showViewControllerModallyInWrapper:] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      +[GameCenterManager dismissWrappedController:] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      +[GameCenterManager unityViewController] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      -[StoreKitManager displayStoreWithProductId:] in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
      ___45-[StoreKitManager displayStoreWithProductId:]_block_invoke in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
      -[StoreKitManager productViewControllerDidFinish:] in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try to clean the project and run.

Comment: First delete derived data and clean the project and run

Comment: done that already. The build fails so there is no derived data

Answer (score 0):

Open the Build Phases for the correct target, expand Compile Sources and add the `UnityGetGLViewController.m` files.Go to the Build Phases tab and then the Compile Sources and make sure you drag the class to the list

Comment: I am missing that file in the project. Could be an issue with a plug -in?